# How to import specific data from an XML file and process it using python 3.5?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have an xml file containing the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="yes"?><!-- Generated by SMExport 4.88--><ROOT>  <RECORDS>
<METADATA><FIELDS><FIELD attrname="SALENUM" fieldtype="i4"/><FIELD attrname="TIME" fieldtype="time"/><FIELD attrname="DATE" fieldtype="date"/><FIELD attrname="AMOUNT" fieldtype="r8" SUBTYPE="Money"/></FIELDS><PARAMS DEFAULT_ORDER="1" PRIMARY_KEY="1" LCID="1033"/></METADATA>
  <RECORD>
    <ROW
      SALENUM="1"
      TIME="125108"
      DATE="20160122"
      AMOUNT="22.9"
    />
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ROW
      SALENUM="2"
      TIME="125243"
      DATE="20160122"
      AMOUNT="22.9"
    />
  </RECORD>
```

plus a whole lot of other records.

Question: What is the simplest way to import this data and process it in python? I am trying to use  xml.etree.ElementTree, what I would like to do in the end is add up the sales prices and store that information in a variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) to locate the `ROW` elements inside `RECORD` elements and [`.attrib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) to access the `AMOUNT` attribute. Complete example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="yes"?><!-- Generated by SMExport 4.88--><ROOT>  <RECORDS>
<METADATA><FIELDS><FIELD attrname="SALENUM" fieldtype="i4"/><FIELD attrname="TIME" fieldtype="time"/><FIELD attrname="DATE" fieldtype="date"/><FIELD attrname="AMOUNT" fieldtype="r8" SUBTYPE="Money"/></FIELDS><PARAMS DEFAULT_ORDER="1" PRIMARY_KEY="1" LCID="1033"/></METADATA>
  <RECORD>
    <ROW
      SALENUM="1"
      TIME="125108"
      DATE="20160122"
      AMOUNT="22.9"
    />
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ROW
      SALENUM="2"
      TIME="125243"
      DATE="20160122"
      AMOUNT="22.9"
    />
  </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
</ROOT>"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
amounts = [float(row.attrib["AMOUNT"]) for row in root.findall(".//RECORD/ROW")]
print(amounts)
```

Prints:

```
[22.9, 22.9]
```

Then, you can use the built-in `sum()` to add up the amounts: `sum(amounts)`.